# Is it possible to migrate all collateral from Pardot to Marketing Cloud seamlessly with an app or some code?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, pardot

I would like to know if it is possible to migrate everything created in Pardot (Engagement Studios, Content, Files, Campaigns, Lists, Dynamic Lists, etc) seamlessly into the Marketing Cloud when a company is migraiting out of Pardot and into the Marketing Cloud (while retaining Salesforce CRM)?

I haven't been able to find concrete answers to this.

​Thank you - Kalina

Answer (score 0):

As the way Pardot is designed is very different from Marketing Cloud, there is no automated or semi-automated way of migrating from one solution to another.

Migrating content, files and html templates should be a relatively easy copy-and-paste job.

However, for the campaigns and engagement studios, you would need someone to rebuild them using Marketing Cloud functionalities such as Journey Builder, Automation Studio etc. This can be quite time consuming and can not be named seamless for sure. Also, you would need to establish a whole new connection between Salesforce CRM and Marketing Cloud which is different from what you may know from Pardot.